# PushViewNavigation Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

Got a real simple question but can't figure out the solution.
Got following code.

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bamEasyTable animated:YES];
```

Simply don't want to load in onto a navigationcontroller but on the view itself (view did load).

have tried almost everything but can't find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show a view ontop of the current view, you can do:

> [self.view addSubview:bamEasyTable.view];

is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah that's it :-)! Thank you, your solution is actually pretty logical haha.. thnx again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the view modally? Generally the navigationController sits at the root level, and any new views are pushed up modally.

```
[self pushModalViewController:bamEasyTable animated:YES];
```

You can always leave the animation off if you want it to cover up the navigation bar instantly, up to you.